# select dropdown option delete from sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to add/remove drop-down options with Javascript. Currently everything works fine except when you select the option you want to delete from the dropdown. Click the delete button deletes the html, but not the sql entry.

EDIT: I edited this to what works for me now, maybe save someone else time. CodeGodie's answer was ultimately correct, but I had to simplify the php and some issues with my config file were messing me up. This simply gives you a text input to add select options and a button to delete selected options. Still needs to be cleaned up and obviously the idea is for an authenticated admin to have this ability, not the free world. Thanks for the help!

Here's my code:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //##### send add record Ajax request to response.php #########
    $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var txt=document.getElementById("contentText").value;  //inputID

            var newcontent = document.createElement('option'); //creates option
             newcontent.innerHTML = txt;
             document.getElementById("choice").appendChild(newcontent); //choice is select ID

            if($("#contentText").val()==='')
            $("#FormSubmit").hide(); //hide submit button
            var myData = 'content_txt='+ $("#contentText").val(); //build a post data structure
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                $("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
            }
            });
    });

    //##### Send delete Ajax request to response.php #########
     window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () {
        var myData = 'choice='+ $("#choice option:selected").val(); 
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        });
       $("#choice option:selected").remove();
        }
    };
});
</script>
<form>
<select id="choice">
<?php
//MySQL query
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT id,content FROM add_delete_record");
//get all records from add_delete_record table
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
$content = $row['content'];

echo '<option>' . $content . '</option>' ;} ?>
</select>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-default" value="Delete" />
    <div class="form_style">
    <input type="text" name="content_txt" id="contentText" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text"></textarea>
    <button id="FormSubmit">Add record</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and the response.php..

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST["content_txt"]) && strlen($_POST["content_txt"])>0) 
{   //check $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty

    //sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH Strip tags, encode special characters.
    $contentToSave = filter_var($_POST["content_txt"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 

    // Insert sanitize string in record
    $insert_row = $db->query("INSERT INTO add_delete_record(content) VALUES('".$contentToSave."')");

}
if(isset($_POST["choice"])){

    $contentToDelete = $_POST["choice"]; 

    $delete_row = $db->query("DELETE FROM add_delete_record WHERE content='$contentToDelete'");

}
?>
```

Comment: put an echo $contentToDelete; right after you sanitize it. Looks like you aren't passing the id to the delete function.

Comment: The `select` should have the `name` attribute.

Comment: chris85 changing the select's attribute stopped the delete button from working. Mr Jack, sorry if this is a stupid question, but if it were getting passed, would it echo something on the form page (since i'm placing it on the php)? Nothing is happening...

Comment: strike that comment, yea, obviously I would have to go to the response.php to see it...I'm getting a sytax error..could be the problem. edit: well I just needed a brace, but now I'm getting an inclusion on the config which is odd because it's adding fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is this line:

```
var myData = 'id='+ $("#id").val(); //build a post data structure
```

theres no element with an id of "id". I believe what you want is the value of the selected. Which in that case would be:

```
var myData = 'id='+ $("#choice").val(); //build a post data structure
```

Also, your code can be a lot cleaner. Since you are using jQuery, i would use jQuery for most of the code, and define repeated elements to a variable so that you can reuse them without having to redefine them again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yea, this is raw, i will clean it. I thought of this too but it didn't work.

Comment: i can probably try helping you remotely through Teamviewer. Let me know if I can assist. I will be on today

Comment: thanks! I wish I had seen your offer to help 2 days ago but i figured it out based on your answer!